# Arround Cauchy Schwarz Inequality in semi riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question.
I seen that Cauchy Schwarz inequality is not valide in the case of pseudo riemannian metric because it is not positive ( or negative) define, I would like to know if there is special cases where this inequality holds, for exemple for spacelike, timelike, .. cases.
Thank you

Comment: Ok thank you, but I don't see exactly how to prove it, so if you have a proof or a link to read more about this case.

Comment: zaar1992: sorry, my comment was incorrect. I have deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a question on linear algebra which can be discussed by just looking at vector spaces with a symmetric bilinear form $g$ (i.e. the nonlinear structure of a manifold is not relevant).

Of course you have the usual Schwarz inequality on subspaces $V$ where the metric tensor is positive (i.e. the restriction of the tensor to $V\otimes V$). The proof is just the same as in the Euclidean case.

In Lorentz space you have in fact the backwards Schwartz inequality: if $v, w$ are timelike vectors in a Lorentz space, then $|\langle v, w\rangle| \ge |v| |w|$ with equaility iff they are collinear.

See, e.g., Barrett O'Neill, Semi-Riemannian Geometry, page 141-144.